# doctest for extracting seconds

Tags: python, testing, doctest

I have a doctest written:

def extract_second(triples):
    """Given a list of triples, return a list with the second element of each triple

```
If an item is not a triple, return None for that element

>>> extract_second([('a',3,'x'),('b',4,'y')])
[3, 4]
>>> extract_second([('c',5,'z'),('d',6)])
[5, None]
>>> extract_second([('a',3,'x'),('b',4,'y')]) ==  [3, 4]
True
"""
for x in triples:
    return x[1]
```

although the code is not returning the 1st index of the 2nd list inputted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are only getting a single answer returned is because the return statement breaks your for loop as soon as it is encountered. it is the equivalent of something like this:

```
for x in list:
     break
 return x[1]
```

And a solution to your problem would be as such:

```
results = []
for i in triples:
if len(i) == 3:
   results.append(i[1])
else:
   results.append(None)
return results
```

This solution appends the answer to a list called *results*, and returns *results* after it is finished iterating through *triples*.